Confusion about Banach Steinhaus
I am currently taking a course in functional analysis and we just learned about the Banach Steinhaus theorem:
Theorem: Let X be a Banach space, Y a normed space, let $\mathcal T \subset L(X;Y)$. Assume that $$\sup_{T\in\mathcal T}\Vert Tx\Vert<\infty,\text{ for all }x \in X.$$ Then $$\sup_{T\in\mathcal T}\Vert T\Vert<\infty. $$
In the tutorials I came about this following counterexample:
Let $$T_n:\ell^1\rightarrow\mathbb R, T_nx = nx_n $$
$T_n$ is linear and bounded as $\vert T_nx\vert \le n\Vert x\Vert$ for all $x\in X$.
$$\sup_{n\in \mathbb N} \vert T_nx \vert = \sup_{n \in \mathbb N} n\vert x_n \vert.$$
But $nx_n\rightarrow 0$ because $(x_n)_n=o(1/n)$ as it is in $\ell^1$ (*). So $nx_n$ is bounded, i.e. the supremum is finite. By Banach Steinhaus we should have
$$\sup_{n \in \mathbb N} \Vert T \Vert < \infty$$ but clearly
$$\vert T_ne_n \vert=n \rightarrow \infty$$
About (*):
Assume an $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}\in \ell^1$ with $nx_n\nrightarrow 0$ exists, then $\exists \epsilon >0 \exists N\in \mathbb N:\forall n \ge N \vert x_n \vert \ge \epsilon/n$. So
$$\Vert x \Vert \ge \sum_{k=N}^\infty \vert x_k \vert \ge \sum_{k=N}^\infty \frac{\epsilon}{n}= \infty$$
Contradiction.
I‘m sure I made an obvious mistake somewhere along the line but I just can‘t seem to find it, any help is appreciated!

"$nx_n\rightarrow 0$ because $(x_n)_n=o(1/n)$ as it is in $\ell^1$ (*)" This is not correct. The issue is that "then $\exists \epsilon >0 \exists N\in \mathbb N:\forall n \ge N \vert x_n \vert \ge \epsilon/n$" is not true.

It should be "then $\exists \epsilon >0 \forall N\in \mathbb N:\exists n \ge N \vert x_n \vert \ge \epsilon/n$"

And indeed $(T_n x)$ might not be bounded: Consider $x = (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $x_n = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} & n = 2^{2k} \text{ for some } k \in \mathbb{N} \ 0 & \text{otherwise} \ \end{cases}$. Then $x \in \ell^1$ but $(T_n x)$ is unbounded.

@Smiley1000 thank you very much, that was a trivial error on my side. Excellent counter example as well!
